# Extending the interface of an exported variable in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations

I'm pretty new to TypeScript, and especially novice at writing/extending declaration files for external packages.

I'm using the [`args`](https://github.com/leo/args) npm package.  It's written in JavaScript, so its type is declared in [`@types/args`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/args).

```js
/** 
 * args/lib/index.js
 */
const publicMethods = {
  option: require('./option'),
  options: require('./options'),
  command: require('./command'),
  parse: require('./parse'),
  example: require('./example'),
  examples: require('./examples'),
  showHelp: require('./help'),
  showVersion: require('./version')
}

function Args() {
  this.details = {
    options: [],
    commands: [],
    examples: []
  }

  /* ... */
}

/* ...assign `publicMethods` to `Args` class... */

module.exports = new Args()
```

```ts
/**
 * @types/args/index.d.ts
 */

declare const c: args;
export = c;

interface args {
    /* ... */
}

/* ... */
```

The `args` class has a private property called `details` (though I don't know why it's private) that is not exposed by `@types/args`.  I'd like to extend the args interface to expose the property so I can iterate over the options, but because the export is a variable and not a module, I haven't figured out how.

I've tried using `declare module`, `namespace`, `declare namespace`, `declare const`, and `declare var`, with and without `import c from 'args';`.  None of those worked, or I did them wrong.

Comment: Related but not working for the args library: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7148

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
type IyourTypeThatExtendArgs = { myProperty: string } & args;
```

This code will create new type for you, and type will extend args type.
Between curly braces you can add your own properties that will be along with args properties.
**&** means extend type which is next to it on right side.